# custom font iphone

Tags: iphone, uifont

I am trying to add a custom font in my app, searched the web, there are many posts but i am getting error

```
InfoPlist.strings:0: error: validation failed: The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted.
```

i dont get what's the issue, i added a new file of font in my project and added this code in plist, i never used plist before

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
<string>CloisterBlack.ttf
</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Accept anyone answer because you have solved your issue. :)

Comment: sorry i thought i checked ur answer coz u helped a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your font file has been corrupted. Add it again and then try.
This link will help you [Add Custom Font in your app](http://kgriff.posterous.com/45359635).
Make sure your file should be **.ttf** . Do you have any **.ttf** file or not ? If YES then add it to you project folder and then make little changes in your **info.plist** file.
[image]

If you dont have any **.ttf** file then download it first. It is your font file.

Comment: i did the same , actually used this tutorial , i dont know may be the font file, i downloaded from 1001fonts, hmm i try to add some font from other web

Comment: You will have download **CloisterBlack.ttf** file then drag it in to your project folder .... and then update it in to your plist like above image.

Comment: i just added my font same as in picture , but still not able to access it with
[UIFont fontWithName:@"CloisterBlack" size:20.0];

tell me the things i should check on

Comment: Have you dragged CloisterBlack.ttf file in your project ?

Comment: we have to find the name of the font, file name is not the font name , check i answered my own question

Answer (score 4):

Add font in plist, then check the name of your font, by double clicking the font file in finder, like in my case the name of the font is Abduction for the font file name "CloisterBlack.ttf"

then access it like

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Abduction" size:20.0];
```

Comment: thanks, took one day then find a post that font name is not the file name !!!! duh. but worked finally

Answer (score 1):

just use [this class](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/fontlabel) for custome fonts

Comment: Just create FontLabel object with font name. add font into project budle.
FontLabel *label = [[FontLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 0, 0) fontName:@"Paint Boy" pointSize:40.0f];
label.textColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
label.text = @"lorem ipsum";
[label sizeToFit];
label.backgroundColor = nil;
label.opaque = NO;
[self.view addSubview:label];

Comment: had many error of ARC, after removing those again had errors other than ARC, will try tomorrow morning, is there any other way

Comment: oky if you are using ARC, then just go to Edit->Refactor->Convert To Objective-C ARC. ARC will be enable in this all classes.

Comment: getting errors in readTable
NSCAssert1(cmapTable != NULL, @"CGFontCopyTableForTag returned NULL for 'cmap' tag in font %@", (font ? [(id)CFCopyDescription(font) autorelease] : @"(null)"));

Cast of C pointer type 'CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *') to Objective-C pointer type 'id' requires a bridged cast

Comment: hi, i have use this in MRC and code is also for MRC. its hard to convert into ARC. so you just need to disable ARC in FontLabel files.

Answer (score 1):

I think adding the extension will fix it, my plist files look the same.

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
<string>CloisterBlack.ttf</string>
</array>
```

Comment: sorry not typed here, but i did type with extension, i edited my question

Comment: I believe the name used in the font file has to be the same as the name of the font file.