# Custom Font for xcode 4.4.1 not working. Custom DIN Font disappears

Tags: iphone, xcode, fonts, uifont

Ive tried system fonts in its place and they appear fine. When I add my custom font the font simply doesnt appear at all. Can anyone tell me what on earth is happening?! Its copied in bungle resources too?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MenuItemCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

  cell.textLabel.text = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  //[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN-Regular.ttf" size:60];
  cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN" size:10.0];

  return cell;
}
```

Nothing appears... not even default system helvetica?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457567/custom-font-iphone/12457748#12457748   Check this link It would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it to Your_Project_name-Info.plist file which might be located in your **supporting files** folder

1. click on **Your_Project_name-Info.plist**
2. Add new object(array)=>type **Fonts provided by application** on key field.
3. Add an object in that array with **name of your font**

Comment: This has also been done, still nothing? thanks for your help. :^)

Comment: Have you checked the spelling of the font?/

Comment: Found out the problem, The DIN font must of been corrupted or something as any other custom font works. So there was no missing link.